# Como hacer una función de un botón?

Tags: c#, funciones

Probé con un botón de busqueda que un usuario me facilito y me funciona a la perfeccion, el tema es que quiero el codigo en una funcion para que yo pueda pasarlo a otros programas y desde el boton llamar a esa funcion.
Botón:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"];
    string texto = textBox3.Text; 
    int posición = tb.Text.IndexOf(texto);

    tb.Focus();
    tb.SelectionStart = posición;
    tb.SelectionLength = texto.Length;
}
```

Había pensado en pasarle el textbox y el texto a la función y así llamar siempre con el textbox y el texto. Y en la función hacer la búsqueda y el resaltado pero no se como hacerlo en código.

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es que en la función del botón llamas la función nueva pasandole el textbox y entonces alli hacer lo que nos propones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas Guille,

Según he entendido en lo que nos planteas, buscas una función donde le pasas el `TextBox` donde hay todo el Texto y el texto que deseas buscar en ese `TextBox`, seria una cosa así:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    ResaltarTexto((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);
}

private void ResaltarTexto(TextBox txtBx, string texto)
{
    int posición = txtBx.Text.IndexOf(texto);

    txtBx.Focus();
    txtBx.SelectionStart = posición;
    txtBx.SelectionLength = texto.Length;
}
```

Comment: Si algo asi, es prácticamente lo mismo pero con la función en una clase diferente pero me sirve para intentar hacerlo de la manera que yo quiero muchas gracias. Un saludo ;)